# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt[n^m]{2} - 1$ For which value of m does this infinite sum converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt[n^m]{2} - 1$$
For which values of m does the converge, and to which values does this converge?

I tested it in Wolfram Alpha, and it appears that m = 1 diverges, and m = 2 goes to around 1.466.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt[n^2]{2} - 1 \approx 1.46608$$

Is there an exact answer for the number this infinite sum approaches?

I don't have a lot of experience in calculus, my understanding of it is just from online learning.
I have tried to input this into calculators I haven't come to a good answer in anyone of them.

Comment: When asking a question, it will be more likely to receive an answer if you explain what you have tried or where your misunderstanding lies.

Comment: @oliverjones I have clarified it a bit

Answer (score 0):

It should converge for any $m > 1$, by comparison with a $p$-series. Observe:

$$\sqrt[n^m]{2} - 1 = e^{a/n^m} - 1$$

where $a = \ln 2$, and

$$e^{a/n^m} - 1 = \frac{a}{n^m} + \frac{a}{2n^{2m}} + \frac{a}{6n^{3m}} + \cdots$$

by Taylor expansion. Each term is separately summable in $n$ (SO LONG AS $m > 1$), and the sum along $n$ in the $k$-th term is $\frac{a}{k!} \zeta(km)$. If $m = 1$ then the first term isn't summable, and so neither is the whole series by comparison. Then, the series converges to the value given by this new series:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{\ln 2}{k!}\zeta(km)$$

which is bounded above by, for example, $\zeta(m) \cdot (e - 1)\cdot \ln 2$ as $\zeta$ is decreasing. For an exact value, I am not optimistic that a satisfying formula can be found.

Comment: Thank you very much.